# server handover document template - users, security settings (firewall,selinux), packages etc

Tags: linux, configuration, documentation

As part of the handover of our linux application server automated builds I would like to produce a high level "handover document" which captures the key functions and config items. (This is more of a admin process thing, rather than having a useful technical function) (ie it is a snap shot in time, the source of the data is possibly some export script, notes, or configuration management like chef)

A while back, I did some work for a UK government agency to install and configure an application on a linux server, and they provided a standard template which had sections for various configuration items, which presumably they could lodge in some Document management system. Unfortunately I didn't keep a copy of the sections.

Really this should be considered much like a server "resume", just enough to prime a knowledgeable technical user with the important facts about the server.

Quick brain dump, gave the following categories and values;

---

## Server configuration

### Description

XXX is configured as a Web service for the YYY for customer ZZZ

#### Basics

```
public ipv4:        123.123.123.123
hostname:           myserver.mynetwork.country.com
OS:                 MyMonkey Linux  0.1
???
```

### Network Configuration

Service

```
Service         port           network
sshd            22             public
httpd           80             public
mysqld          3306           localhost
```

### Application configuration

(this is usually going to be some web app)

```
Platform:               PHP 5.3, mysql 
public  URL:            http://someplcae.com/wefwefwef
log file location:      /var/log/httpd/whatever.log
```

Admin Interface
admin URL
admin username
admin password?

### Security Configuration

```
selinux:            Enabled
SSH Root Login:     Disabled
SSH password auth:  Enabled
Compliance Level:   None
```

Package Updates:    Manual

### OS level Configuration

```
Mounted Storage:           None
kernel parameters:           None
```

### Backup configuration

```
Software:           None
Storage:            None
```

---

Is there anything else that *you* would want to see in a high level document, if I was handing the server over to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Obvious one: The root password
- SSH keys if applicable
- In case of self-signed SSL certificates in the infrastructure, all files relevant for the private CA
- Dependencies for other systems in both directions:

  - If service X on Server Y fails, what happens to this server
  - If service Z on this server fails, what happens to other systems
- Any non-standard and non-obvious configuration options and local quirks

I guess I could come up with a lot more as I currently work my way through creating this kind of documentation for the group of servers and workstations I inherited as part of my new job without any info at all.

Comment: yeah, I can see that about the service dependencies, but I was thinking that could get a bit length. I guess things that are direct dependencies like databases and file servers